# Flutter package to code a restaurant app which prints receipts using thermal Bluetooth printer

Tags: flutter, point-of-sale

So, I'm new to Flutter development and I have some experience in developing some apps but nothing I'm complicated. I wanted to develop an app that selects the entered dishes and quantities displays the total calculated amount and prints a receipt using a thermal Bluetooth printer.

But I have tried almost every package like esc*-pos-*utils, flutter-blue-plus, Bluetooth-print, etc. But not one package helped me even discover the Bluetooth devices.

Which package should be used and should I be coding it in Dart or should I use a different language to code in?

I have tried almost every package like esc*-pos-*utils, flutter-blue-plus, Bluetooth-print, etc. But not one package helped me even discover the Bluetooth devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using blue_thermal_printer package as it include all the basic feature you need for printing and the concept of connecting and printing is almost the same for these type of package
refer more at
[the pub.dev page](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_thermal_printer/example) or the [github example](https://github.com/kakzaki/blue_thermal_printer/tree/master/example/lib)